# Opencart add product options to opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

My cart appears to be working except the product options. When I click add cart button then the item gets added, but no options are added with it. I really don't understand why this is happening as I have submitted the options as an array just as the function requires, using `option_id` and `option_value_id`

JavaScript called when button is clicked

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    var model_select = $('#model option:selected').val();

    alert("working");
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $action?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'option' : $('#network option:selected').val(),'product_id': model_select, 'ajax':'1'},
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
    });
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['product_id']) && isset($_REQUEST['option'])) {
            $product_id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];
            $option=array("13" => (int)$_REQUEST['option']);
            var_dump($option);
            $this->cart->add($product_id,$quantity=1,$option);
            print_r($this->session->data['cart']);

        }
```

Here is the `var_dump` of the options array

```
array(1) { [13]=> int(60) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** Option($key=>value) where you have passed $key => 13 which should be valid key

in array of `Option($key=>$Value)` where `$key` represents `product_option_id` and `$value` represents  `Product_option_value_id` of `product_option_value` table so these should be valid which is assigned dynamically when you assign option to product rather than static id.

****Second**** Just use the default method of opencart, this will handle other input type as well

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }

                if (json['error']['profile']) {
                    $('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>');
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this the only way to use the option array. for instance i have an option array of $option[$option_id] = $value, which returns like
Array
(
    [14] => 358762050821738
)
and my cart session data is
Array
(
    [60:YToxOntpOjE0O3M6MTU6IjM1ODc2MjA1MDgyMTczOCI7fQ==:] => 1
)

The option is of type text using an input from a textbox from the user.

Comment: Solved thank you, the options array had to be $option[$product_option_id] = $value;
i had to call the product option id from the databse using the option id and product id.