# Opencart cart.add() with option

Tags: ajax, opencart, send

I'm looking for solution in opencart.

Need to rebuild cart.add function for adding product with option value.

By default:

```
'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#cart > button').button('loading');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

            $('#cart > button').button('reset');

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        }
    });
```

checkout/cart/add php side for option:

```
        if (isset($this->request->post['option'])) {
            $option = array_filter($this->request->post['option']);
        } else {
            $option = array();
        }
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I used the solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161192/4288232

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following way. Create a simple `Javascript` object.

```
var productData = {'product_id' : PRODUCT_IDS.CARD, 'quantity': 1,'option':{'229':"Some option value"}};
```

And send the request as follows. Converting the object to `post params` using the `param` function.

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $.param(productData),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                    },
                    success: function (json) {

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                    }
                });
```

Also there are some other ways to do this, you can see possible payload formats in the `/controller/checkout/cart.php` file.