# Add to cart button when a product has a required option in OpenCart 2.3.0.2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, opencart, opencart2.x

How would one go about adding required options to an ajax call after clicking an add to cart button?

Currently the code in the common.js is:

```
var cart = {
'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index1.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {           
            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                 $.notify({
                    message: json['success'],
                    target: '_blank'
                 },{
                    // settings
                    element: 'body',
                    position: null,
                    type: "info",
                    allow_dismiss: true,
                    newest_on_top: false,
                    placement: {
                        from: "top",
                        align: "right"
                    },
                    offset: 20,
                    spacing: 10,
                    z_index: 2031,
                    delay: 2000,
                    timer: 1000,
                    url_target: '_blank',
                    mouse_over: null,
                    animate: {
                        enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
                        exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
                    },
                    onShow: null,
                    onShown: null,
                    onClose: null,
                    onClosed: null,
                    icon_type: 'class',
                    template: '<div data-notify="container" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-3 alert alert-success" role="alert">' +
                        '<button type="button" aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-notify="dismiss">×</button>' +
                        '<span data-notify="message"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp; {2}</span>' +
                        '<a href="{3}" target="{4}" data-notify="url"></a>' +
                    '</div>' 
                 });

                $('#cart_block #cart_content').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #cart_content_ajax');
                $('#cart_block #total_price_ajax').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #total_price');
                $('#cart_block #cart_count_ajax').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #cart-total');
                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
            }
        }
    });
},
'update': function(key, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index1.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            } else {
                $('#cart_block #cart_content').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #cart_content_ajax');
                $('#cart_block #total_price_ajax').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #total_price');
                $('#cart_block #cart_count_ajax').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #cart-total');
            }           
        }
    });         
},
'remove': function(key) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index1.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'key=' + key,
        dataType: 'json',           
        success: function(json) {
            if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                location = 'index1.php?route=checkout/cart';
            } else {
                $('#cart_block #cart_content').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #cart_content_ajax');
                $('#cart_block #total_price_ajax').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #total_price');
                $('#cart_block #cart_count_ajax').load('index1.php?route=common/cart/info #cart-total');
                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
            }
        }
    });         
}
```

}

Obviously, options are not added in this call to add it to the cart. I did managed to show the options, you can see an example here:

https://www.amsterdamvapes.com/eleaf-istick-pico-set

There you will see 7 related products, all with 1 required option.

The related options are getting saved in a $product['options]' array and they're showed by this code in the product.tpl file;

```
<?php if ($product['options']) { ?>
      <div class="options">
        <?php foreach ($product['options'] as $related_option) { ?>
        <?php if ($related_option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
        <div class="form-group<?php echo ($related_option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-option<?php echo $related_option['product_option_id']; ?>"><?php echo $related_option['name']; ?></label>
          <select name="option[<?php echo $related_option['product_option_id']; ?>]" id="input-option<?php echo $related_option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control">
            <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($related_option['product_option_value'] as $related_option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $related_option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $related_option_value['name']; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

In the product.tpl file the add to cart button gets this code;

```
<li><a onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>','1','<?php echo $related_option_value['name']; ?>');" class="btn-secondary btn-buy"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a></li>
```

I can understand I would have to add all the possible options to that onclick function where the product_id is added. And then add code to the common.js to get the options from that onclick event but I have no clue on how to do that.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction to add those option values to the ajax call?

Sincerely hope anyone can help out! Cheers, David

Comment: I can add an answer for you if you like or you can look at the default OpenCart template's product page. There's a script at the bottom, it shows that all inputs from the product's possible options (not necessarily the ones on the page) are sent in the ajax call. That should resolve your problem, in fact, it may be better for you to use that script rather than your own (if you don't have additional logic).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your quick answer! I did see that piece of code, I wasn't sure if I could use that or not. Is it possible for you to let mee see what parts I should edit / add?

Comment: I've had to customise a few sites and found options weren't going through to the cart, I later realised that the input ID's had changed and so I added the new ID's to the `data: $(<<inputs>>),` line and it worked perfectly! It also ensures you have a visible confirmation that the item has been added to the cart - which your site doesn't appear to have

Comment: @Daniel the visual confirmation is there and works if you add a normal product. The products that show in the related products have it too if the product doesn't have a required option :) Can you tell me what files I have to edit and what I need to add exactly? I'd be forever grateful!

Comment: David your theme appears to have the script I mentioned in the expected place. Could you share a link to a product with options? The link you shared shows the Eleaf iStick Pico set and there are no options for a guest user.

Comment: @Daniel thanks a lot for looking at it! Here's a product with options: https://www.amsterdamvapes.com/accessoires-e-sigaret/coils/eleaf-melo-iii-mini-nano-ec-coils thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152462/discussion-between-daniel-and-david-weermeijer).

Comment: I used the solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161192/4288232